# unmask custom properties in the log files

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer, mask

I have a wix setup project, I build it and install it using following command line:

```
msiexec /i setup.msi /l* log.txt
```

My project has properties which are used by textboxes.

```
<Property Id="DataSource" Value="."/>
<Control Id="DataSourceText" Type="Edit" Text="." Height="17" Width="150" X="200" Y="18" Property="DataSource"/>
```

Those properties don't display in the log file. Is there a way to make them displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Use upper case for property names and they will.</s>

I use `/l*v` option to get the verbose log from MSI. All events where a value is assigned to a property are logged, along with the new value. (This holds true both for upper-case *public* properties and mixed-case *private* properties.)

If a property holds a password or other sensitive information, it should be marked with attribute [`Hidden="Yes"`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_property.htm). The values of such properties are not logged.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 Is your property listed in [MsiHiddenProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370308.aspx)? If yes, then it should not be logged.

Comment: I didn't list it there explicitly. I'll take a look in Orca tool.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 Does adding `v` to log options (`/lv*`) not help either?

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 I updated the answer. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this topic: there's still a difference between /lv* and /lvoicewarmupx which uses all the log options.

With the second option you see the initial value of the properties as well.

```
zzz.msi /lvoicewarmupx debug.log
```